# DC pop with audio input switching in radio unit

Tags: switches, dc, noise, radio, sound

I'm working with an older 1980s car stereo.
I added aux by cutting signal trace to tone control module (which goes: signal -> caps (100nF x2 in parallel, by design) -> tone control IC -> some more resistors and caps -> amps -> output) and putting a **DPDT** low signal PCB relay there.

The relay is switching between my aux and any other audio signal.

The relay coil has a reverse biased 1n4148 **diode** on its legs and is switched to 5V DC via a low side switch (adding or subtracting ground to relay).
I measured the draw of relay (ca. 35mA) and calculated the **RC snubber** (arc protection) cap and resistor parameters. Used slightly larger, i.e. 220nF and 33ohm in series over switch contacts.

**There is an audible DC pop when switching to or from aux.**

So I added a simple attenuator for aux input cable. Then, a bleed resistor to chassis ground from positive audio input of radio, with 10K values, right before relay. The IC (tone control) side of the relay got also bleed resistors to chassis with 1.5M values. Too high?

It did not change the pop and it occurs even when my aux socket is empty (so I did not add similar resistors on aux wire), so it seems to be related to a discharge down the line.
Perhaps the amplifier related capacitors? Should I add a resistor to ground on each positive audio wire directly preceding the output socket for speaker? It is very hard to access on this PCB, and I am getting out of ideas.
I will appreciate any help, because it is getting out of my level of expertise and I cannot find a clear answer in the forum.

Thank you,
F

[image: Input and IC side resistors marked with downstream pathways for your reference]

Latest version of my circuit here:

[image]

Comment: Well what is the DC bias set by the original source? If it is different from your alterate source which has 0V bias, yes there will be a pop when caps charge or discharge to new bias. But you also have the arc suppression RC over relay contacts, please draw your new relay circuit to understand how it works - it might cause the snap. Why would audio signals need arc suppression?

Comment: I added all the elements later on, after first testing just the relay with just the aux, was causing a pop. Everything added on top is not improving things. I'll try to draw it. How do I measure DC bias? Multimeter DC mode on the radio input signal that is going to relay?

Comment: @Justme the DC measured at audio speaker output is about 10mV, with FM mode on and low volume, no station tuned to. The pop is over 100mV.
Almost got the schematic done but CircuitLab locked me out...

So right now I have 5uF bipolar caps on aux R and L singnal wires, followed by 1k resistor and then 10k resistor to audio aux ground wire. 

I added wires at DPDT relay input legs to 1M resistor each, resistors are joined together on their other end and then wire to chassis/main ground.

Comment: [continued] The pop is still there...

I tried 100ohm resistor from (+) amp input to (-) amp input (4 total, since there are 2x TDA2005). I've read about here in someone else's answer. Got no sound at all.

Someone mentioned adding a big capacitor (3200uF) from positive relay coil leg to chassis. I'm skeptical.

I'll try to draw it by hand and post here. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Also, the SPDT switch in my circuit is part of the original radio, so I cannot remove or change it. I have a Velleman HPS40, but I'm not sure what my next step should be. There is no space for fancy microcontrollers or even NE555 with another relay to mute the amps briefly while switching.

Comment: @fpxd - Hi, You wrote an "answer" below, which was actually an update as it didn't answer your original question. On Stack Exchange, updated information either goes into the answer via an [Edit] (if it's relevant to all readers) or as a comment (if you are just replying to one person). An update must *never* be posted using the box below labeled "Your Answer" - unless you have solved the question yourself and want to close the topic. Please stop editing your "non-answer" - it has been *deleted*. Please read the [tour] and [help] to get a better idea how this site differs from typical forums.